# Empty exception args when is caught from another module in Python

Tags: python, exception, module, pytest

Note the following Python code:

```
import pytest


def test_validate_number():
    number = 2
    try:
        verify_number(number)
    except AssertionError as exc:
        raise exc


def verify_number(number):
    assert number == 3, 'Incorrect number'
```

When executing this code and of course the exception is caught the args tuple value is shown below, which is fine with me because I need the assert values **assert 2 == 3**

```
'Incorrect number
assert 2 == 3'
```

The problem is when the same code is executed and the exception is caught from another module, for example:

**helpers.py**

```
def verify_number(number):
    assert number == 3, 'Incorrect number'
```

**test_numbers.py**

```
import pytest

from tests.helpers import verify_number


def test_validate_number():
    number = 2
    try:
        verify_number(number)
    except AssertionError as exc:
        raise exc
```

When the exception is caught from another module like this, the exception args tuple only has the assertion message and not the assert values like this:

```
'Incorrect number'
```

Why does this happen? I need those values **assert 2 == 3**

Comment: In what environment do you execute the code ? That is not a classic error that you show at first, to display a variable. `assert 2 == 3` is not supposed to be printed in your first either

Comment: @azro this is just a generalised example

Comment: Yes but you're saying : that first code works, that second don't, except both don't. Just show what you need ;) The given answer for now solves that

Comment: I want to know technically why this happens.

Comment: I can't reproduce either of your exception messages. I get this in both cases: `assert number == 3, 'Incorrect number'
AssertionError: Incorrect number`

Comment: @quamrana sorry an import is missing, edited

Comment: @quamrana and if you debug it and search within the Exception args tuple?

Comment: Why do you have the `except AssertionError` clause in the first place if it only reraises the exception?

Comment: No specify reason, it is just an example

Comment: are you sure this is actually in the args tuple, and not just some extra info printed out by pytest?  either way I find it hard to believe these two scenarios behave differently

Comment: Yes, pretty sure. I find it hard to believe myself hence why coming to ask for help from more experienced people :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because it has caught the `AssertionError` from `verify_number` and the value stored in `exc` is the text `Incorrect number`. It then raises that exception.

To get the value of `number`, try this:

```py
def verify_number(number):
    assert number == 3, f'Incorrect number: {number} != 3'
```

And it will then output `Incorrect number: 2 != 3`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why don't I get the same Exception args when I'm executing the same code but in a different module?

Comment: @WineTorpedo What you're talking about *does* not happen, I can't reproduce, others don't too in the comment, no matter if the exception is catch in the same file or throught 10 files, it doesn't changes it at all